# How do I install packages?

Tags: r

After i tried to install a package in R i can't install packages anymore, it's somehow blocked. I get this box with the question if i want to create a personal library etc. and if i press yes the same box comes again and again, if i press no then comes a box that says unable to install packages. I've tried several solutions but nothing has worked. Any ideas? I'm really desperate cause I can't go further with my studying for the university. Thanks in advance!

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling R and Rstudio, closing Firewalls and Antiviruses, opening Rstudio as administrator. Maybe i've done somthings the wrong way, so any tips from zero point would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the actual error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

I had used R-studio for exploratory Data analysis a few months back. I also faced the same issue, some times R-studio refuses to install packages, so what I did was uninstall the IDE and install it again, it starts from the beginning and loads up with default configuration. Once installed I used the command

```
install.packages('tidyverse')
```

Here's the link to official R-studio IDE documentation :

https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/200554786-Problem-Installing-Packages-in-the-RStudio-IDE

The above solution worked for me.